# OpenText eDOCS 10 server API on Windows 2012R2 error "Cannot load the DM Server interface. The DM server may not be started."

Tags: windows, api, windows-server-2012, dcom

I have been tasked to upgrade some custom software to work with OpenText eDOCS 10 server API on Windows 2012R2. Previously the software was running with the eDOCS 5.3.1 server API Windows 2008R2.

I cannot get the eDOCS server API to work on Windows 2012R2. The error is "Cannot load the DM Server interface.  The DM server may not be started.".

I created a C# test console program to get the eDOCS libraries via the eDOCS API. This program does NOT work (error above) on Windows 2012R2 with eDOCS 10, but DOES work on Windows 2008R2 with eDOCS 10.
The account that executes the program is member of the "Distributed COM users" local group. The test program executes in a elevated DOS box.

As the eDOCS API is implemented with COM objects and a C# interop dll, **my suspicion is that something is off with the COM/DCOM/COM+ configuration on a Windows 2012R2 server** for the eDOCS components.

I have verified and compared the COM+ activation and access for the "OpenText eDOCS DM Server" component with the 2008R2 configuration.

What am I missing? Has Windows 2012R2 a hardened COM/DCOM/COM+ security?

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question. There was definitely something off. A colleague responded with the solution:

Somehow, things get fixed when the "DM Connection Wizard" is run.

[image: DM Connection Wizard page 1]

After clicking "Next" on this first page (and I did not even finish the wizard), the server API started to work and my test program showed the loginlibraries!

I finished the wizard anyway on the second page.

[image: DM Connection Wizard page 2]

Answer (score 0):

To add to [Victor's solution](https://superuser.com/q/1165917/150988#1166796):

Recently my site upgraded OpenText eDOCS from v10 to v16.5.  Their instructions tell you to run their eDOCS Library Upgrade Utility. But attempting to do so was smacking into this same error message Victor originally posted about.

When running the DM Connection Wizard, I noticed that it was defaulted to HTTPS as the protocol.  I had a vague recollection that the API that allows our legacy app to call into their API did so via DCOM. So I changed the dropdownlist choice to DCOM and that seems to have gotten me past the problem of my simple TestApp not being able to login. And I was able to have the simple TestApp call upon their API's prefab Search form and was able to get it to list prior Documents I'd previously added into that server.

Comment: It is important when dealing with Techie issues to NOT edit SOMEONE elses answers to the point of leaving out whole parts of the post. For you have no idea how many times, for me personally, seeing all the other side-issues related to a problem has helped me overcome a similar situation I've been faced with.  Now... you'll feel compelled to do what you'll do, and I can't stop you from doing that. Just know that unnecessarily editing for terseness to the point of lopping off whole paragraphs of someone elses words is just plain rude and unproductive, we all can just scroll down brother.

Answer (score 0):

I find that the issue is often due to incorrect or missing `Server`, `Protocol` and `Port` settings. You can confirm the server, the protocol and the port info prior to an upgrade by first going into to the Registry at the following path.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Hummingbird\Clusters
```

Then go into the DM Connection Wizard and enter that info there after the upgrade is installed and it should launch without issue.